# Measure of a Borel set.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: [0,1)\rightarrow [0,1)$ be defined by
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases} 
\hfill 2x   \hfill & x < \frac12 \\
\hfill 2x-1 \hfill & \frac12\le x<1 \\
\end{cases}$$
Suppose $E$ is a Borel subset of $[0,1)$ such that $f^{-1}(E)=E$. Use a density point argument to show that $m(E)=0$ or $m(E)=1$.

I have tried to use the symmetry of the preimages of $E$ to imply the measure of $E$ is arbitrarily close to 1 and therefore equal to 1. However, I still stuck on this. Could you help me with this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convenient here to use addition modulo $1$ on $\mathbb T = [0,1)$, i.e. consider $\mathbb T$ as the quotient group $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$.  With this interpretation, $f(x) = x + x = 2 x$.

If $x, y \in \mathbb T$ with $x - y = 2^{-n}$ for some positive integer $n$, then $f^n(x) = f^n(y)$, so $x$ and $y$ are either both in $E$ or both in $E^c$.  That is, $E + 2^{-n} = E$, and $E$ is invariant under translation by $2^{-n}$.

Now if $m(E) > 0$, then $E$ has a point of density $p$, and then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $n$ such that $m(E \cap (p-2^{-n-1},p+2^{-n-1}]) > (1-\epsilon) 2^{-n}$. Translating by multiples of $2^{-n}$, we get that
$m(E \cap (p + k 2^{-n} - 2^{-n-1}, p  + k 2^{-n} + 2^{-n-1}]) > (1-\epsilon) 2^{-n}$ for all $k$.  Using $2^n$ such translates, the intervals $(p - k 2^{-n}- 2^{-n-1}, p  + k 2^{-n} + 2^{-n-1}]$ cover all of $\mathbb T$, and we get $m(E) > 1 - \epsilon$.  Since this is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, $m(E) = 1$.